# What are the prospects of suing with China over COVID-19?

Tags: united-states, law, international-relations, international-law, china

Recently, some group of US jurists started [suing](https://www.theweek.in/news/world/2020/03/24/20-trillion-lawsuit-in-us-against-china-for-using-covid-19-as-biological-weapon.html) (original probably [here](https://images.law.com/contrib/content/uploads/documents/392/85094/Coronavirus-China-class-action.pdf)) with China over COVID-19 outbreak, blaming PRC for incorrect actions during pandemia, caused harm for the US.

Does this lawsuit has any prospects?

Comment: I'm not a legal expert, but I suspect that the Foreign Sovereign Immunities Act would make it highly unlikely that such a lawsuit would be successful.

Comment: @JoeC: this is speculation, of course, but with enough [public] outrage, Congress could override FSIA again, as they [did in case of Saudi Arabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_Sovereign_Immunities_Act#Notable_legal_cases) (concerning 9.11)

Comment: in general, international lawsuits fare poorly.

Comment: With respect to the District Court of Northern Texas I doubt it has jurisdiction over the government of China; if it claims to have jurisdiction I doubt China will submit. I wonder if the suit is more for PR purposes rather than a genuine belief in a realistic prospect of a win for the plaintiffs?